# Redirect one URL to another on same domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I am currently building a new website. The old website has different url's than the new one. Now i want to redirect, using htaccess.

Before going live, i want to test my rules locally.

The old website uses url's of this format:

```
www.domain.de/?content=whatevercontent
```

The new website uses url's of this format:

```
www.domain.de/index.php?content=differentcontentname
```

Which are rewritten (in the htaccess file, using several RewriteRules) to this format:

```
www.domain.de/nicecontentname
```

I tried Redirects like this:

```
Redirect http://domainfolder/?content=whatevercontent http://10.3.10.69/domainfolder/nicecontentname
```

This does not work.

After going live it should work like this:

```
Redirect http://www.domain.de/?content=whatevercontent http://www.domain.de/index.php?content=differentcontentname
```

..and then be rewritten to the nice url.

My Redirect-Rules just won't apply, i tried it in all combinations i could think of, with or without http, with or without the containing folder, using the already rewritten url or the actual one, etc..
Any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use Redirect directive to manipulte querystrings. Here is a mod-rewrite example that works for QueryStrings :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/\?content=this
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?content=that [L,R]
```

This will temporary redirect **/?content=this** to **/index.php?content=that**

To make the redirect permanent (browser cacheable) change R to R=301.

Comment: Thanks starkeen. Could you give an example without regex, just a single rewriterule which i can then alter for several urls?

Would this be: 
RewriteRule /index.php?content=differentcontentname$ /?content=whatevercontent